# Is Qt's debugger good for segmentation faults?

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

I'd just use Valgrind, but I'm forced to use Windows 7. I saw the post on Valgrind alternatives, but if possible I'd like to stay native with Qt and just stick with that. Are there any features for their debugger which truly help in this regard?

Comment: You can always use Windows 7 to run a virtual machine with Linux, Qt, and valgrind installed on it.... ;)

Comment: Run whole Windows 7 under valgrind? Thats crazy

Comment: No.  Run the Qt program under valgrind, run valgrind under Linux, run Linux under a VM, run the VM under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt debugger use standard CDB debugger on Windows. This is not like Valgrind, just a regular (GDB-like) debugger